# Python Program error - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, temporary-files, shutil

I am trying to test a python code which moves file from source path to target path . The test is done using pytest in Python3 . But I am facing a roadblock here. It is that , I am trying to remove the source and target paths at end of code completion. For this I am using a command like shutil.rmtree(path) or os.rmdir(path)  . This is causing me the error  - " [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". Please help me on this. Below is the python pytest code:

```py
import pytest
import os
import shutil
import tempfile

from sample_test_module import TestCondition
object_test_condition = TestCondition()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_value",['0'])
def test_condition_pass(test_value):
    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    temp_src_folder = 'ABC_File'
    temp_src_dir = os.path.join(temp_dir , temp_src_folder)
    temp_file_name = 'Sample_Test.txt'
    temp_file_path = os.path.join(temp_src_dir , temp_file_name)
    os.chdir(temp_dir)
    os.mkdir(temp_src_folder)
    
    try:
       with open(temp_file_path , "w") as tmp:
           tmp.write("Hello-World\n")
           tmp.write("Hi-All\n")
    except IOError:
        print("Error has occured , please check it.")
    org_val = object_test_condition.sample_test(temp_dir)
    print("Temp file path is : " + temp_file_path)
    print("Temp Dir is : " + temp_dir)
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
    print("The respective dir path is now removed.)
    assert org_val == test_value
```

Upon execution of the code, the below error is popping up :

> [WinError32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptryggg56'

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the directory you are trying to remove is the current directory of the process. If you save the current directory before calling `os.chdir` (using `os.getcwd()`), and `chdir` back to that directory before removing `temp_dir`, it should work.

Your code isn't correctly indented, so here is my best guess at what it should look like.

```
import pytest
import os
import shutil
import tempfile

from sample_test_module import TestCondition
object_test_condition = TestCondition()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_value",['0'])
def test_condition_pass(test_value):
    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    temp_src_folder = 'ABC_File'
    temp_src_dir = os.path.join(temp_dir , temp_src_folder)
    temp_file_name = 'Sample_Test.txt'
    temp_file_path = os.path.join(temp_src_dir , temp_file_name)
    prev_dir = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(temp_dir)
    os.mkdir(temp_src_folder)

    try:
       with open(temp_file_path , "w") as tmp:
           tmp.write("Hello-World\n")
           tmp.write("Hi-All\n")
    except IOError:
        print("Error has occured , please check it.")

    org_val = object_test_condition.sample_test(temp_dir)
    print("Temp file path is : " + temp_file_path)
    print("Temp Dir is : " + temp_dir)
    os.chdir(prev_dir)
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
    print("The respective dir path is now removed.)
    assert org_val == test_value
```

Comment: can you represent your idea in the code ? It can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to close the **temp** file before removing

`temp.close()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).